# How can I migrate database from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, data-migration

I am replacing an Access application with a web app, but the client is using SQL Server 2000, and I am using SQL Server 2008.

So, I have the database redesigned, with foreign keys, but now I need to get the data on the client's system.

Part of the problem is that they have images that are over 32k, so osql failed as the command buffer filled up.

I should be able to use osql to import the new schema at least, and perhaps all of the data except for the images.

The Export wizard just wouldn't work, even though I tried the Native SQL Driver and the OLE DB Sql Driver.

Flat files seems like a bad choice, as I don't know if it can do the images.

So, what is a good way to copy a 330M database from 2008 -> 2000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the image column to null, which reduced the size of the insert statements.

This enabled me to import the data into the target database.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about performance or time needed, but you could always try a tool like

- Red-Gate [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) / [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm)
- Apex [SQL Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.asp) / [SQL Data Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.asp)

These will allow you to compare both the schema of two databases, as well as the data, and allow you to create synchronization scripts, or synchronize online.

Marc